# Find if array exists in multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have a multidimensional array that look like this:

```
Array


[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => ACURA
        [1] => CL
        [2] => 3.2L V6 F/I
        [3] => Blue
        [4] => 33-2133
        [5] => 33-2133
        [6] => V6
        [7] => F/I
        [8] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => ACURA
        [1] => CL
        [2] => 3.2L V6 F/I
        [3] => Blue
        [4] => PS-1004
        [5] => PS-1004
        [6] => V6
        [7] => F/I
        [8] => 
    )
```

)

I then have another array that looks like

```
   Array
(
    [0] => ACURA
    [1] => CL
    [2] => 3.2L V6 F/I
    [3] => blue
    [4] => HP-1004
    [5] => HP-1004
    [6] => V6
    [7] => F/I
    [8] => 
)
```

Is the a way to look through the multdimensional array and see if the single array exists already in the multidimensional array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `in_array()` should work.

[Link to PHP manual.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

In the changlog it mentions that as of 4.2.0 the needle (search) can be an array...

Comment: This does not seem to work. I'm guessing because it can't search a multidimensional array. It always returns false.

Comment: @JasonSmall -- `in_array` is sufficient if you're only dealing with two dimensions.

Comment: @rdlowrey You are correct. I had the needle and haystack reversed.